# Какой есть аналог шрифта CiscoSans?

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Существует ли аналог шрифта CiscoSans (Cisco Sans)?

Вот сам шрифт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй что-то из списка

```
Roboto
Open Sans
Lato
Source Sans Pro
Proxima Nova
```

Эти шрифты имеют схожие характеристики с `CiscoSans` и могут использоваться в качестве замены, хотя и не являются точным соответствием. При выборе шрифта важно учитывать общий дизайн и читабельность текста, а также любые рекомендации по брендингу или дизайну, которым вы можете следовать.

Comment: Noto мне нравится.